# Unusual usage of the word "parentheses"

Tags: word-usage

In [this](https://youtu.be/YWZAL64E0DI?t=3379) video I heard the following sentence:

> Our ability to constantly confuse the real with the metaphorical,
> **parentheses**, our brain's evolutionary challenge to have come up with
> something as novel as moral abstractions..

Can the word "parentheses" act as the verbal equivalent for adding parentheses in writing?

Comment: In theory. People do say, "It's a, quote, thing," when they want to express the verbal equivalent of *it's a "thing"*. But if that were the case here, I'd expect there to be two instances of *parenthesis*, or an *open parenthesis* followed at some point by a *close parenthesis*. Otherwise, what exactly is being enclosed in parentheses in that sentence? Even if the use is okay (not that I've ever encountered it), the implementation here seems to be faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In speech, people normally quote others using the grammatical construct of backshifting:

> he said that he had nearly finished the report

When they use the words quote and unquote around a phrase, they generally do so to indicate that they are referring to a phrase that other people use but they personally disagree with.

There is no grammatical construct for parentheses (or, in my opinion, any reason to have one), and no alternative meaning assigned to using the word "parenthesis". I cannot see any reason for this speaker to use the word. As Jason mentioned in his comment, to be strictly correct, you would have to say open parenthesis ..... close parenthesis, which would be very long winded.